# Ping Request Timeout when AP connected to the network

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, switch

Currently I have

- Rv320 router connected to the internet
- e900 cisco Wi-fi router as Access Point conected with DD-WRT to the Rv320
- Hp 1920 switch connected to the Rv320

The problem is that I'm experiencing intermittence eventualy when I ping some other machine or the switch.

Looks like this occours only when the Access Point is connected to the Network.

- router rv320 192.168.1.2/24
- router AP e900 192.169.1.1/24
- switch 192.168.1.4/24

every machine uses Gateway 192.168.1.2
and I have a Dnsmasq DNS on 192.168.1.20

Firstly I was getting a big sequence of timeout and after reseting and reconfiguring the Access Point I was able to get justo some eventual ping timeouts.

How can I disgnose and solve it?